# Force credit card payments in Express Checkout even if user is logged in to paypal

Tags: php, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal

I've created two `PayPal\Api\WebProfiles` for express checkout. The first one (`Billing`) leads the user to the Non-PayPal account landing page. The second one (`Login`) leads them to the PayPal account login landing page.

This procedure works fine if the customer is not already logged in to paypal.

However, if he is, i've found that regardless of which WebProfile I use, paypal only shows the credit card options only when the paypal balance is not enough for the transaction.

Is it possible to force paypal to show the credit card payment option in this case?

Comment: I believe PayPal will always try to use the PP balance first.

Comment: thank you for posting this - I didn't know about these Web Profiles - pretty cool